# How to draw specific type of colour at some row col in assembly?

Tags: user-interface, x86, bios, real-mode

I want to know how to draw a particular pixel on screen at given row, col in assembly in 16 bit real mode for boot sector? Also how can I know width and height of screen?

Comment: To draw single pixels, you'd have to switch the screen to graphics mode, not text mode (the default when a legacy-BIOS MBR bootloader boots.)

Comment: Use [INT 10h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) for a switch to graphic videomode. Arrangement of each mode is described in the table at this link. For instance, the usual mode 13h (320*200) is set by `AX=0013h; INT 10h`, videomemory starts at `A000:0000`, addressing the top-left pixel.